# Can't fetch Page.RouteData.Values in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-routing

I am trying to enable routing on an asp vb.net application.

I followed the next steps :

1) In global.asax,there is this code

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    End Sub
</script>
```

2) In the RouteConfig.vb i have this :

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls

Public Module RouteConfig

    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)
        routes.MapPageRoute("Services",
            "Services/{SID}",
            "~/Services.aspx")
    End Sub

End Module
```

3) In the services.aspx page, i wrote this

Imports System.Web.Routing
Partial Class Services
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        lblTest.Text = RouteData.Values("SID").ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

When I run the page, I get the error message

"No object reference is specified in an object instance."

If I delete the line "lblTest.Text = RouteData.Values("SID").ToString" it is working, of course without the SID parameter

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"No object reference is specified in an object instance"* known as another wording to indicate [`NullReferenceException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) besides common "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*" message. Since you're mentioning this line:

```
lblTest.Text = RouteData.Values("SID").ToString
```

The exception occurs when `RouteData.Values("SID")` contains `Nothing`, and `ToString` cannot work with `Nothing` set as its source string. You can check if `RouteData.Values` has `Nothing` using [`RouteData.Values.ContainsKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822608/routedata-valueslanguage-tostring-generat-null-exception):

```
If (Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("SID")) Then
    lblTest.Text = RouteData.Values("SID").ToString
End If
```

Since you're using `MapPageRoute` with `FriendlyUrls`, I think you need to rename URL in second argument to another different name than physical ASPX file name, preventing `Nothing` passed as URL argument:

```
' note 's' omitted in Service/{SID} route
routes.MapPageRoute("Services", "Service/{SID}", "~/Services.aspx")
```

Then, you can try reordering statements inside `RegisterRoutes` so that `EnableFriendlyUrls` executed after `MapPageRoute`:

```
Public Module RouteConfig

    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.MapPageRoute("Services", "Service/{SID}", "~/Services.aspx")

        Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Similar issues:

[FriendlyURLs - RouteData returns no value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046377/friendlyurls-routedata-returns-no-value)

[Page.RouteData.Values are empty for one page but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746022/page-routedata-values-are-empty-for-one-page-but-not-another/26151214)